# How to prevent stack overflow when using Scala's Predef.implicitly

Tags: scala, stack-overflow, implicit-conversion

Given this simple code snippet I am astounded to provoke a stack overflow this easy:

```
implicit def foobar: Unit = implicitly[Unit]
```

In my little more complex use case I have the following situtation:

```
abstract class Foo {
  type Repr_Tpe
  protected implicit def repr2Ordered: Repr_Tpe => Ordered[Repr_Tpe]
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  type Repr_Tpe = Long
  protected implicit def repr2Ordered = implicitly[Repr_Tpe => Ordered[Repr_Tpe]]
}
```

Defining method `repr2Ordered` in class `Foo` does not work because type `Repr_Tpe` is abstract. So I decided to copy & paste the declaration and make a definition out of it; **apparently leading to the stack overflow from above.** Only by removing the modifier `implicit` from the definition in class `Bar` solves this problem.

Isn't there an elegant solution circumventing this pitfall?

Comment: Could not the Scala compiler easily detect this situation since the definition is in the process of definition?

Comment: The reason for this error is that you are defining something that you want to return. So it's pretty sophisticated way to write recursive function. Seems that you have taken this example out of context. Some more context information and some explanation about what you really trying to archive with this code would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Scala's type system is turing complete, and that turing completeness is a result of implicit inference. That means anything using implicit type inference is pretty much bound by the same rules as any running program, among which the impossibility of predicting program termination -- the exact same problem you have here. Something could be done for the simplest cases, but not for the general case.

Comment: Hm, the examples compile and run fine on my machine (2.9.1.final). What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined `foobar` to *be* the implicit value of type `Unit`. Then you've defined it *as* the implicit value of type `Unit`. Thinking of it this way:

```
implicit def foobar: Unit = implicitly[Unit]
// you've defined foobar as the implicit value for Unit.
// so implicitly[Unit] is the same as calling foobar
// which is the same as:
implicit def foobar: Unit = foobar
```

You should be no more surprised that this causes a stack overflow than you would be by this statement:

```
def tharSheBlows: Unit = tharSheBlows
```

For something with a bit more elegance, I would use a [view bound](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-and-view-bounds.html) to ensure that the type paramater is `Ordered` instead.

```
scala> abstract class Foo[Repr_Tpe <% Ordered[Repr_Tpe]] {}
defined class Foo

scala> class Bar extends Foo[Long] {}
defined class Bar

scala> case class Unordered(data: String)
defined class Unordered

scala> class Bam extends Foo[Unordered] {}
<console>:10: error: No implicit view available from Unordered => Ordered[Unordered].
       class Bam extends Foo[Unordered] {}
                 ^

scala> implicit def bringOrder(u: Unordered) = new Ordered[Unordered] { def compare(that: Unordered) = u.data.compareTo(that.data) }
bringOrder: (u: Unordered)java.lang.Object with Ordered[Unordered]

scala> class Bam extends Foo[Unordered] {}
defined class Bam
```

Comment: Given the first two code snippets the recursive nature becomes clear to me. Your proposal to use parameterized types instead of abstract types won't work for me not because of technical issues but of a design decision.

Comment: My conclusion is to declare `implicit` abstract members but **never** their definitions. Am I right with this assumption?