# Can you specify a view bound for an abstract type?

Tags: scala

In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9455947/115478) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9447071/115478), I was surprised that the following code doesn't work.

```
scala> abstract class Foo {
     |  type Repr_Tpe <% Ordered[Repr_Tpe]
     | }

<console>:2: error: `=', `>:', or `<:' expected
```

The OP says that replacing the abstract type with a type parameter isn't an option. Is there any way to express a view bound for an abstract type?

Answer (score 7):

There certainly is.  A view bound `A <% B` on a type parameter is just sugar for "an implicit value parameter with type `A => B`".  What you want, then, is to say that:

```
abstract class Foo {
    type Repr_Tpe
    implicit def orderify: (Repr_Tpe => Ordered[Repr_Tpe])
}
```

Of course implementations will have to provide an actual implementation of `orderify` at the same time they specify the type.  Probably something like

```
class Bar extends Foo {
    type Repr_Tpe = Int
    val orderify = implicitly[Int => Ordered[Int]]
}
```

or

```
class Baz[A <% Ordered[A]] extends Foo {
    type Repr_Tpe = A
    val orderify = implicitly[A => Ordered[A]]
}
```

Comment: This example works, but I'm not sure why. Why don't the `implicitly` statements in `Bar` and `Baz` resolve to `Foo.orderify`?

Comment: It's because local scope (which for these two subclasses includes either the implicit `evidence$1` or the implicitly imported `Predef.intWrapper`) is considered more specific than the inherited `orderify`.

Comment: Actually no, I'm wrong about that.  The imported `intWrapper` shouldn't be more specific than `orderify`.  The compiler is deliberately excluding `orderify` from the search while redefining it, which I guess makes sense but I don't see how that proceeds from the spec.